# Instantiating a parameter pack of template parameters

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, variadic-templates, c++17

I'd like to make a template that takes a pack of templates and instantiates them with the same argument pack.

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to expand a parameter pack inside a  parameter pack of templates.

How can I make this compile?

```
#include<type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <template <typename...> typename... Args>
struct TupleTupleMaker
{
    template <typename... InstantiateWith>
    using NewTupleTuple = typename std::tuple<Args<InstantiateWith...>...>;
};

template<typename a, typename b>
using tuple1 = std::tuple<int,a,b>;

template<typename a, typename b>
using tuple2 = std::tuple<a,b,b>;

using expected = std::tuple<
    std::tuple<int,int,double>,
    std::tuple<int,double,double>>;

using actual = TupleTupleMaker<tuple1,tuple2>::NewTupleTuple<int,double>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<actual,expected>, "Should be same");
```

Comment: `tuple1` is not `template <typename...> typename Args`, which seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the direction of [core issue 1430](https://wg21.link/CWG1430), you can't pack expand into an alias template with a fixed parameter list. The workaround is to rewrite `tuple1` and `tuple2` by routing them through a class template:

```
template<class a, class b>
struct tuple1_impl { using type = std::tuple<int,a,b>; };

template<typename... a>
using tuple1 = typename tuple1_impl<a...>::type;

template<class a, class b>
struct tuple2_impl { using type = std::tuple<a,b, b>; };

template<typename... a>
using tuple2 = typename tuple2_impl<a...>::type;
```